# Load panorama from assets folder or URL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-play-services, panoramas

I have been using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Panorama 60.1142.0-rc1 package in order to show a simple fullscreen panorama activity. The following code successfuly starts panorama activity from fragment:

```
public async void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + Activity.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.pano1);
    var panoramaResult = await Android.Gms.Panorama.PanoramaClass.PanoramaApi.LoadPanoramaInfoAsync( googleApiClient, uri);

    if(panoramaResult.Status.IsSuccess)
    {
        if(panoramaResult.ViewerIntent != null)
        {
            StartActivity(panoramaResult.ViewerIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "WTF?!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However, if i try to load the same panorama jpg from assets or URL, like this:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///android_asset/panorama/pano1.jpg");
```

or like this:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xzs424/RBCPrototypeChallenge/master/PanoramaSampleActivity/res/raw/pano1.jpg");
```

panoramaResult.ViewerIntent is null, and there is no activity to start. Documentation says that ViewerIntent should be null if image is not Google panorama, but all three parts of the code use the same image, only it's in different places. So, is there a way to load panorama image from any place other than raw folder in resources? Note that I also tried latest stable Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Panorama, which at the time of writing was 42.1021.1, without luck.